# Como hacer que un TextView muestre el contenido de un Array si lo estoy recorriendo con un ciclo For

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

Tengo un Array de int que almacena las Preguntas en modo de (ID) por esta razon no es de tipo String.
Tengo otro Array de booleanos que almacena las respuestas correctas.

> La idea original es que un ciclo for recorra el Array de preguntas y
>   el contador muestre lo que hay en las determinadas posiciones mediante
>   el TextView Posterior a ello el usuario deberia presionar el boton de
>   cierto/falso para darle el valor a una variable que sera comparada con
>   "respuestaCorrecta" para que al final retorne un Toast que dira
>   correcto o incorrecto segun se cumpla la condicion con un if/else
>   sencillo.

**NO LOGRO HACER QUE EL TEXVIEW MUESTRE LO QUE SE ENCUENTRA EN LA POSICION "n" DEL ARRAY DE PEGUNTAS.
COMO PUEDO HACER QUE EL TEXVIEW MUESTRE CADA UNA DE LAS POSICIONES.**

### QuizActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class QuizActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private int mostradorPregunta;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);


         //= findViewById(0x7f060029);

        //COMIENZA EL ARRAY DE PREGUNTAS

        int preguntas [] = new int[3];
        preguntas [0] = 0x7f060025;
        preguntas [1] = 0x7f060026;
        preguntas [2] = 0x7f060027;
        preguntas [3] = 0x7f060028;


        //COMIENZA ARRAY DE RESPUESTAS

        boolean respuestaCorrecta [] = new boolean[3];
        respuestaCorrecta [0] = true;
        respuestaCorrecta [1] = false;
        respuestaCorrecta [2] = false;
        respuestaCorrecta [3] = true;

        TextView mVisorPregunta = new TextView(this);
        mVisorPregunta.setText(mVisorPregunta);

        for (mostradorPregunta = 0; mostradorPregunta < preguntas.length; mostradorPregunta++){
            mVisorPregunta = mostradorPregunta;
        }




        mTrueButton = findViewById(0x7f0b005e);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
                  public void onClick (View v){
              Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
            });



        mFalseButton = findViewById(0x7f0b005f);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
                public void onClick (View v){
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.incorrect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        });

    }
```

### strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">GeoQuiz</string>
    <string name="question_text">¿LOS GATOS TIENEN DOS OJOS?</string>
    <string name="true_button">Cierto</string>
    <string name="false_button">Falso</string>
    <string name="correct_toast">Correcto!</string>
    <string name="incorrect_toast">Incorrecto!</string>

    <string name="pregunta1">¿El cielo es azul?</string>
    <string name="pregunta2">¿Android es desarrollado por Apple?</string>
    <string name="pregunta3">¿Los gatos pueden respirar bajo el agua?</string>
    <string name="pregunta4">¿Las aguilas pueden volar?</string>
</resources>
```

### activity_quiz.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="@string/question_text"/>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/true_button"
           android:id="@+id/true_button"/>
       <Button
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/false_button"
           android:id="@+id/false_button"/>

   </LinearLayout>






</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Layout del activity_quiz.xml]

Answer (score 0):

Esto:

```
 int preguntas [] = new int[3];
    preguntas [0] = 0x7f060025;
    preguntas [1] = 0x7f060026;
    preguntas [2] = 0x7f060027;
    preguntas [3] = 0x7f060028;
```

Te debería estar marcando un **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** pues le estás diciendo que tu arreglo es de 3 posiciones y le estás metiendo 4.

Cambia esta línea:

```
int preguntas [] = new int[3];
```

Por esta:

```
int preguntas [] = new int[4];
```

Comment: en los arrays el 0 cuenta...

Comment: ¿En qué lenguaje?

Comment: Pues es Java, yo los declaro así y no me genera errores :)

Comment: Pues debería. Cuando declaras un arreglo y defines su dimensión el número que le pongas es literalmente el número de espacios que aceptará. El index 0 se usa para la asignación de valores. Un arreglo definido new int[5] dice literalmente que solo puede sostener hasta 5 espacios (indexs 0,1,2,3,4)

Comment: Me parece que el compañero tiene razon, en cualquier caso, no pasa a mayores. Pues lejos de mostrar 4 preguntas, solo mostraria 3 (0, 1, 2)

He probado con ambos casos, y en ningun se muestra un error. No ha sido relevante al momento de la solucion del probema. Pues justamente el `.length` que aplico dentro del for en el Array **preguntas** solventa ese problema.

Comment: Bueno, revisaba tu código y no llegué a la línea del for porque vi lo del index que comenté. Qué bueno que resolviste tu problema, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

lo que yo haría, sería lo siguiente:

```
ContadorPreguntas=0;
mTrueButton = findViewById(0x7f0b005e);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
                  public void onClick (View v){
              Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              if(ContadorPreguntas<preguntas.lenght()){
              ContadorPreguntas++;
              mVisorPregunta.setText(preguntas[ContadorPreguntas]);
              }

          }
            });
```

Lógicamente, haría lo mismo con el botón de falso.
Te explico, agregué un contador llamado `ContadorPreguntas` que servirá para saber el índice del array del cual debe buscar la respuesta, lo inicio en 0. antes de modificar el valor del contador, verifica que este no sea mayor al tamaño del array (para evitar `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`), si el contador es menor al tamaño del array, entonces le suma 1 al contador y actualiza el TextView con la propiedad `setText` en el cual le paso el array preguntas con índice `ContadorPreguntas`

**EDIT**
el siguiente código es incorrecto:

```
TextView mVisorPregunta = new TextView(this);
```

en android, debes de *castear* al elemento del XML:

```
TextView mVisorPregunta=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.algo) //"algo" es el ID que tiene mVisorPregunta en tu XML
```

Comment: El resuelto el problema a medias, te comento que resolvi que el TextView espera otro `TextView` pero yo envio un `int`, por lo que ese Array lo converti de int a un Array de `TextView´s`  y `mVisorPregunta` le doy como valor a mostrar el Array en la posicion `motradorPregunta`, pues es quien tiene la posicion de la pregunta.

Quedando asi: `for (mostradorPregunta = 0; mostradorPregunta < preguntas.length; mostradorPregunta++){
            mVisorPregunta = preguntas[mostradorPregunta];
            mVisorPregunta.setText((CharSequence) preguntas[mostradorPregunta]);`

Comment: AHORA NO PUEDO CORRER EL APP EN MI TELEFONO

Y aun no estoy seguro, (pues soy novato en Android) de que ese TextView pueda ver que esta cambiando.

Que lineas son las que le dicen esto al XML?

Comment: no sé si aún te sea, útil, pero actualicé mi respuesta @AlexisOlveres